# How do I make a texture similar to the ones on Subtle Patterns, but with colour?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, patterns, texture

I really like this texture:

[image]

There's a million similar to it on [Subtle Patterns](http://subtlepatterns.com), but they're all white, grey or black for the most part. How would I take one of those and make it a dark blue, like in that image? Or a dark green?

Answer (score 3):

- Make a blue layer (or whatever color you want)
- Apply a Pattern Overlay layer style to it
- Change the blend mode of the Pattern overlay to interact with the color of the layer (Multiply, Screen, Color Dodge, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The patterns is really simple, so it might be better to re-construct it yourself in order to be able to apply colors to your heart's contempt.

To create the pattern, start with a line (or very long rectangle), rotate it 45 degrees and duplicate it until you cover the artboard.

[image]

Once you are happy with the result, crop it so it remains seamless when turned into a pattern. This usually means trying to use the less possible space, so you will depending on the line width, end up with one or more diagonal lines. Join the shapes, and apply any color you want. When done, go to `Edit > Define Pattern`:

If you want to use thin lines, your pattern will en up looking something like this:

[image]

You can find more [detailed instructions here](http://designs.blackwidowbalm.com/2013/05/how-to-creating-a-diagonal-line-repeating-pattern-in-photoshop/). There's also this [**online stripe generator**](http://www.stripegenerator.com/) that makes the process quite easy and outputs in different formats.

Comment: While this helps in creating your own patterns, it really doesn't address the question of "How do I change the color of an existing pattern?" That being said the question's title, and the question asked in the body of the question are actually two different questions.

Comment: @Johannes I considered Scott's answers covered that, so I just added the info on how to do it from scratch. Either his or Scott's is the way to go, mine is added information.

Answer (score 2):

We can accomplish a lot with just blending modes.

Just open up the pattern in question in Photoshop.

Now create a new `Color fill Layer` or simply create a new layer and fill it with the color you want.

The `Color` blending mode works great when you're using colors. Note that dragging the color more towards a tint, tone, or shade (White, gray, black respectively) the underlying pattern will become more apparent (as there is less color for the `Color` blending mode to work with)

`Overlay` is also a good blending mode to play around with as it will simply overlay the color on top. However, `Overlay` will only add to whatever is underneath, it will not replace it. So for instance if you have a gray pattern, and you overlay white, you will end up with a lighter gray, but not the full white.

There may be other blending modes that work for you too, so make sure to explore them all.

One other method to try out is using a `Hue/Saturation Layer` (or selecting the layer and directly using `Hue/Saturation` on it `Image -> Adjustments -> Hue/Saturation`

Also, if you're dealing with a very simple texture that maybe uses just some solid colors (no gradients or crazy texture), then `Image -> Adjustments -> Replace Color` to swap out one color for another can work great.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in photoshop, your best route IMO is to make a solid color (black) pattern.

1. When you want to apply it to something, take the layer you're appling it to, and duplicate it.
2. Add the striped pattern to the top layer, the one you duplicated.
3. Now take that layer with the pattern on it, and reduce the fill to 0%. Now you should have a patterned layer in the shape of the layer you want to add the pattern to, sitting directly over the original layer.
4. Create a new blank layer, and merge it with the layer with the pattern on it. Not you have a flat layer of the pattern, in the shape you want.
5. Now you can add color overlays, gradients, more patterns even? to the pattern layer, and just generally have more control over the pattern.

This approach is why you normally find things like geometric patterns coming in either white or black, rather than a wide range of colors. Once you have it saved to your patterns library, you have all sorts of control over it.